# PC-less, direct backup? (ADB apps+data, call logs, SMS, contacts, AndroidManifest, app metadata, settings, etc.)

Tags: backup, external-sd, sd-card

**How can these data be backed up directly in the phone itself (i.e. MicroSD, USB-OTG) without needing a PC?** Is it also possible without Root?

- All SMS messages.
- Call logs.
- All contacts and phonebooks.
- Calendar
- Applications and data. (either all or manually selected applications)
- (lesser relevant) Battery statistics. (I have ccc.bmw71.pro (does stand for *battery monitor widget,* not for *Bayerisches MotorWerk* this time.) for that purpose. But it **overwrote bmw_history.txt.**)
- App Metadata (AndroidManifest.xml, installation date, store, usage statistic, etc.)
- Settings, other metadata and usage statistics if possible, but that is lesser relevant.
- Anything else. (NANDROID would require rooting.).

Data by third-party messaging applications is usually included into application data.

Comment: Titanium backup is the answer but requires root. See the tag for it

Comment: Without root not possible

Comment: Yes and no. They can – but not without root or [tag:nandroid]. And btw, Nandroid doesn't require root, but an unlocked bootloader only.